# How can I clear / refresh my terminal after printing special characters?

Tags: terminal, zsh

Sometimes, I print data with special characters. After that my terminal looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it is useless to `clear` the terminal.

Is there any way to get back to normal after special characters were printed except for closing the terminal and opening it again?

Comment: Looks like more of a SuperUser question to me. Don't post a second question there, though... maybe flag for mod attention and see if it's a good candidate for being moved.

Comment: @JDB: Ok. But why the -1?

Comment: Don't know... wasn't me. Someone probably thought the question "wasn't useful". (See tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

When you see such a mess on the screen `reset` command is your friend. Basically it will reset all special characters to their default values and re-initializes your terminal. Most probably you have this command in the system under /usr/bin directory as a link to `tset`.

If for any reasons `reset` is not present then you can run `echo -e \\033c` where `\\033c` is a special code, which should be read as *ESC c*.

You can even clean your terminal from other terminal with a little help of `cat` command. For example if your problematic terminal resides on /dev/pts/3 then run the following sequence:

```
$ cat >/dev/pts/3
ESC c, ENTER, Ctrl-D
```

and /dev/pts/3 should be cleaned up.